# Rigify can't generate my rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

Rigify can't seem to generate my rig because of an issue relating to the nose. It says "bpy_prop_collection(key): key "ORGnose" not found. Which is weird if you ask me because there are nose bones placed on Van's face (The character) [image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably deleted bones from the face. Rigify needs **all** of the facial bones to generate the rig.

Or you may have disconnected some of the bones that need to stay connected.

I have made a video about the face rig
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8aCBKjPJRE

There is also a whole playlist of videos where I tried to explain how to avoid most of the annoying errors that Rigify throws at you.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJv68SSdwxip33M7snakl6Dx